# Android wearable - how to auto install wearable app

Tags: android, wear-os

I have created two simple modules in my android project. One module is called handHeld and the other module is called wearable.  in the manifest of handHeld i set wearable as a dependency (it was set for me already by the system).  I was expecting that when i load handHeld onto a device that it would automatically synch wearable onto the watch but im not seeing that on the emulator (after doing a port fwd).  Communication between the watch and device works as i can see notifications appearing and synched.  How can i get my wearable app to load onto the watch at the same time as when i install handHeld module onto my device ?

Comment: Are you installing a release build?

Comment: Its release build with release keystore. Two apk s generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only auto-install with an app signed with a release keystore, if you're building the debug version you will need to manually add it to your watch with adb.

> Note: The automatic installation of wearable apps does not work when
>   you are signing apps with a debug key and only works with release
>   keys. See [Packaging Wearable Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) for complete information on how to
>   properly package wearable apps.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

Comment: Its release build with release keystore. Two apk s generated